# Quotient ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is it true
$Q[x]/\langle(x-1) \rangle \subset $
$Q[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2) \rangle$ ?

What do you think about that?

Plus Is $Q[x]/\langle(x-1) \rangle$  a subring or ideal of $Q[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2) \rangle$?

I thought like the below but I'm not sure whether right or not.

Here is a My thought

As a point of view of the set, the two set are disjoint hence neither subset nor subring(or ideal).

Comment: While others have already made comments, I would like to add that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle (x-1)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}$. Moreoever, by the chinese remainder theorem, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle (x-1)(x-2) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle(x-1)\rangle \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle (x-2) \rangle$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle(x-1)\rangle \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle (x-2) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. So, the second ring has an isomorphic copy of the first. However, as drhab mentions, they are not subsets hence not subrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if $I,J$ are ideals of ring $R$ with $I\subseteq J$ then the function $\nu:R/I\to R/J$ prescribed by $r+I\mapsto r+J$ is a well defined surjective ringhomomorphism.

This reveals that $R/J$ is isomorphic with a *quotient* of $R/I$.

Observe that the underlying sets of these rings are *distinct* if $I\neq J$.

So it is out of the question then that one is a subring of the other.

Applying that on:

- $R=\mathbb Q[x]$,
- $I=\langle(x-1)(x-2)\rangle$
- $J=\langle(x-1)\rangle$

we find that $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle(x-1)\rangle$ can be looked at as (isomorphic with) a quotient of $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2)\rangle$.

Comment: Starement)Let the ring $R$ and its ideal $I$ and $J$ s.t. $I\subset J$
Then there is a subring(or ideal)  $R_J(\simeq R/J)$  of  the   $R/I$.  Then Is statement true?

Comment: The ringhomomorphism $\nu:R/I\to R/J$ as described in my answer has a kernel $J/I=\{j+I\mid j\in J\}$ which is an ideal of $R/I$. This with $(R/I)/(J/I)\simeq R/J$.

Answer (score 1):

The third isomorphism theorem shows that for a commutative ring $R$ and ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ with $I\subseteq J$, $R/J$ is isomorphic to $(R/I)/(J/I)$. So as said above, $R/J$ is isomorphic to a quotient ring of $R/I$.